# When use $_GET to get string in cakephp plus bacome blank

Tags: cakephp

I'm use $_GET to get str in cakephp like this.
  `$str = $_GET['str']` ,and the url like be this `http://test.loc/test.php?str=sss+sss`

And the `$str` is going to be `sss sss`, plus become `blank`.
And I want to get the `$str` be `sss+sss`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your life easy ;)

CakePHP has methods which handles with request & response.

**https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html**

example:

```
// return string || null
$str = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('str');

// replace blank / white space with + character
$str = str_replace(' ', '+', $str);

// or better use Text class
$str = Text::slug($str, '+');
```

**https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/text.html#creating-url-safe-strings**

**Note:**

> '+' are special characters in the query component